# Zend: Is this CakePHP Query Builder where() call vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, zend-framework, where-clause, sql-injection

```
$linkedStudies = $this->LinkedStudies->find('all')
->where(array(
'is_citation' => true, 
'protocol_ids REGEXP' => '^([0-9]+)*'.$id.'([0-9]+)*$'
));
```

(I am using CakePHP and MySQL with the Zend framework.)

Note the $id variable in the where clause.

Comment: Another one bites the dust. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* vulnerable to SQL injection, because the expression will be passed as a proper parameter to the query by CakePHP. (Thanks @ndm for pointing this out below!)

Note though that using user input in regular expressions is a potential denial of service vulnerability, because it's relatively easy to deliberately create a regexp that will be *very* slow on anything but small inputs.

In case of the above, it would be a good solution to only allow `$id` from a hardcoded set (validate it in php to be from a given list), because `protocol_ids` sounds like it has a finite number of possible values.

Comment: "It is technically vulnerable to SQL injection due to string concatenation." - Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: See the last paragraph for this particular case.

Comment: If that snippet uses the CakePHP query builder then it's not vulnerable to SQL injections, as the right hand side of array style key > value conditions will be subject to binding, except if it's an object that implements the expression interface.

Comment: @ndm Apologies, you are ofc right, thank you for pointing this out! I should have properly read the question. The DoS argument still holds though, so I will fix my answer instead of deleting it.